# Orange Pi Zero LTS, Compiling Xradio Drivers

Tags: linux-kernel, orange-pi, armbian

Hello people of the internet,

I am trying to compile and load the Xradio driver into armbian. I have successfully compiled the kernel but when I try to compile the drivers it says it trys to refrence a make file that doesn't exist in the kernel source. It has to be possible to compile it for ambian since a version of the xradio driver is loaded onboard already.

- https://github.com/fifteenhex/xradio
- https://github.com/armbian/build.git

I am able to compile and load the drivers with the legacy kernel, but it crashes the network manager almost instantly since I am not using the legacy kernel onboard.

- https://github.com/orangepi-xunlong/linux-orangepi

I am aware of the terrible nature of these drivers... And sorry for my terrible spelling.

Compile the Xradio Driver using Armbian on a OrangePi Zero LTS